# TV Umpire replaced by Robot (machine)

Tags: robotic-arm, robotics-toolbox

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_umpire

Is it possible using Robotics, Artificial intelligence, Machine learning technologies to replace the TV umpire - Human by a Robot (machine)?

i.e. The Robot will take the decision whether the batsman is out or not out after watching the replays.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Prashant Akerkar, but I'm afraid that opinion polls such as this are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*.  Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).  Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: As it has been explained to you before on 6 different SE site now, the most important thing missing from you questions is research effort. Linking a Wikipedia article or a Google search is not research effort. It also doesn't help that you have been blocked on other sites because you are accused of trolling. Please show more research effort before asking.

Answer (score 1):

No robotics, machine learning or AI required. Tennis relies heavily on [HawkEye](https://www.hawkeyeinnovations.com/sports/tennis) technology for a while now, static high speed cameras and analytical dynamic models. Hawkeye also makes progress in [cricket](https://www.hawkeyeinnovations.com/products/ball-tracking/cricket-decision-review-system) and other sports.