# Robot performing soldering functions using Soldering iron

Tags: industrial-robot, artificial-intelligence

Is it possible to design and construct a Robot which can solder components using a Soldering iron on printed circuit boards?

If No, What are the limitations?

[image][image][image]

Comment: What are exact requirements? You attached pictures of a toy robot, most basic soldering iron and some random PCB, but tagged the question with industrial-robot and AI. So what do you want to do? A hobby project that can break every couple of components? Or industrial machine soldering thousands of chips reliably?

Comment: Thanks. Industrial robot soldering components on pcb.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Prashant, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: of course it is possible ... a person can design and build almost anything, if desired .... furthermore, how do you know that such a robot does not already exist? ... there are robots that do accurate spot welding ... a soldering tool would not be much of a change

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar are you a real person? ... no offense , but you ask what appear to be unreseached, if not naïve questions that seem to be designed to determine the response of the people here

Comment: Real or not, the behavior seems to have been going on for some time.  https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/21440/tv-umpire-replaced-by-robot-machine#comment35103_21440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are many soldering robots in existence today.  Unfortunately, they don't look very humanoid.  They are usually simply gantry style robot arms.  They are common on manufacturing lines.

Remember that a robot is just a machine.  And machines are designed to do a specific task, usually as efficiently as possible.  And this usually means simple, straightforward, and with the fewest extra degrees of freedom.  So a humanoid robot doesn't really make sense for this task.

Some quick google searches turn up many examples:

[image: HU-200 Robotic Soldering System]

[image: QUICK Soldering Robot]